# C# - How can I convert the string value to decimal places?

Tags: c#, string, format, decimal

Basically, ive created a form that I can select different shapes that when a value on the track bar is selected, works out both the area and boundary length of either a circle, triangle or square.

The values are currently coming through with a lot of decimal places and I want to set up radio buttons to choose whether 2, 3 or 4 decimal places.

```
private void sliderBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        textBox3.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();

        if(circleButton.Checked == true)
        {
            textBox2.Text = (circle.getArea(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
            textBox1.Text = (circle.getBoundLength(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
        }
        else if(squareButton.Checked == true)
        {
            textBox2.Text = (square.getArea(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
            textBox1.Text = (square.getBoundLength(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Text = (triangle.getArea(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
            textBox1.Text = (triangle.getBoundLength(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
        }

        if (decimalPlaces2Button.Checked == true)
        {
            TextBox2.Text = decimal.Round(textBox2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToDouble();

        }
}
```

Comment: Decimal.ToDouble() can take an argument.  Just look at the MSDN article for the method.

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal(value)

Comment: There is a typo, `TextBox2.Text = decimal.Round(textBox2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToDouble();` should be `TextBox2.Text = decimal.Round(textBox2.Text /* HERE */, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToDouble();`

Comment: @CallumLinington gives an error: the best overloaded method match for 'decimal.Round(decimal, int, System.MidpointRounding)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Yeah so you need to surround `textBox2.Text` with `Double.Parse(textBox2.Text)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution which does not Round your number.

```
static double TakeDecimals(double value, int decimalCount)
    {
        var truncation = Math.Pow(10, decimalCount);
        return Math.Truncate(value * truncation) / truncation;
    }
```

Called like

```
var input=24.343545;
TakeDecimals(input, 2);//24.34
TakeDecimals(input, 3);//24.343
TakeDecimals(input, 4);//24.3435
```

UPDATE

In your case, having a string, you can do `Convert.ToDouble(yourString)` before calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Math.Round(double, int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Math.Round(value, 2);
```

Comment: so, textBox2.Text = Math.Round(value, 2); ?

Comment: the value is already a string though? it gives an error saying 'The name 'value' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: what should I put in instead of value do you think?

Comment: You'd need to parse the Textbox2.Text value using [Double.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First convert string to decimal using "Convert.ToDecimal". Then use "Math.Round" to round the decimal number(2, 3 or 4 decimal places).

```
decimal area;   
textBox3.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();

    if(circleButton.Checked == true)
    {
    area = circle.getArea(trackBar1.Value)
        textBox2.Text = area.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = (circle.getBoundLength(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
    }
    else if(squareButton.Checked == true)
    {
    area = square.getArea(trackBar1.Value)
        textBox2.Text = area.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = (square.getBoundLength(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
    area = triangle.getArea(trackBar1.Value)
        textBox2.Text = area.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = (triangle.getBoundLength(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
    }

    if (decimalPlaces2Button.Checked == true)
    {
    decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(area);
        decimal numWithTwoDecimalPlace = Math.Round(number1, 2);
            TextBox2.Text = numWithTwoDecimalPlace.ToString();
    }
else if (decimalPlaces3Button.Checked == true)
    {
    decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(area);
        decimal numWithTwoDecimalPlace = Math.Round(number1, 3);
            TextBox2.Text = numWithTwoDecimalPlace.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: hi @Nat you have specified a string number, but in my program this number will change in the form depending on where the marker on the tracker bar is

Comment: decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);

Comment: Use your string value as above .

Comment: it has accepted the code but does not update it in the text box in the form

Comment: try
{
    decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
    decimal numWithTwoDecimalPlace = Math.Round(number1, 2);
    TextBox2.Text = numWithTwoDecimalPlace.ToString(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

Comment: it seems to have done the same again Nat, not updating in the text box

Comment: I think you should change your code like below. 
 decimal area;  
 textBox3.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();

        if(circleButton.Checked == true)
        {
     area = circle.getArea(trackBar1.Value)
            textBox2.Text = area.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = (circle.getBoundLength(trackBar1.Value)).ToString();
        }

        if (decimalPlaces2Button.Checked == true)
        {
  decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(area);
      decimal numWithTwoDecimalPlace = Math.Round(number1, 2);
             TextBox2.Text = numWithTwoDecimalPlace.ToString();
        }

Comment: I got your previous statement working so thanks for that, but when I try and create it as a if else statements for else if (decimalPlaces3Button.Checked == true) , it wont accept it, any idea why?

Comment: I have changed the code in my first answer. Please look in to that. You have to assign calculated value to variable before doing any changes. See the "area" variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
    decimal convertedValue;
    decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text,out convertedValue);
   textBox2.Text = Math.Round(convertedValue, 2).ToString();
```

Comment: @Math.Round(convertedValue, 2); is giving me an error stating cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'

Comment: sorry just use toString() :
textBox2.Text = Math.Round(convertedValue,2).toString();

Comment: does this all go in the one line?